# How to understand Azure Application Insight blank space in profiler transaction details

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I'm trying to understand why some pages of our application takes so long to load.

It's a .NET Core MVC Web App. It's working fine and fast locally but once it's deployed on Azure some pages randomly takes very long to load.

Using Application Insights profiler I can see in the transaction details that all the dependencies are loaded in a few milliseconds and then nothing happens during more than 30 seconds before the transaction resolves.

[image: End-to-end transaction details screenshot]

Is there any diagnostic tool (or do I miss a pane somewhere) to identify **why there's this long inactivity period** holding the request?

Comment: Could you please share the code base , will take a look.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT What do you mean by "code base"? The controller action code?

Comment: Can you [enable profiler for AppService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json) ? This will profile requests and help to find bottlenecks. See [10 minutes episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzqNIvHryE0) on usage of profiler with App Service